# SQL Server : chain grouping of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, sql-server-2014

I need group two different columns with the following rules:

1. If an order is split into multiple containers, all those containers must be in the same group
2. If any of the grouped containers has multiple orders, each order needs to be processed in the same group (like group C in the results). When this happens and the order belongs to another group the groups need to be merged. This can lead to large chains...
3. Every other container can be processed on its own and does not belongs to a group

I have the following data:

[image]

My aim is to create a View which should return the following result:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53948252/sql-grouping-similar-rows#comment94734986_53948252

Comment: Thanks, that is almost exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

This is a graph-walking problem.  You need to walk the graph of linked containers to get all possibly container linked to the order.

My solution is then to aggregate to get the minimum value and use `dense_rank()` to assign the grouping.

```
with cte as (
      select orderid, containerid, containerid as linked_containerid,
             cast(',' + convert(varchar(max), containerid), ',') as containers
      from t
      union all
      select cte.orderid, cte.containerid, t.containerid,
             cte.containers + convert(varchar(max), t.containerid) + ','
      from cte join
           t
           on cte.containerid = t.containerid and
              cte.containerid not like '%,' + convert(varchar(max), t.containerid) + ',%'
     )
select cte.orderid, cte.containerid,
       dense_rank(min(cte.linked_container)) over () as grouping
from cte
group by cte.orderid, cte.containerid;
```

Comment: I tried your script but its not working. Even after fixing the small problems my result is not as expected. But I am thankful, because I now understand how I can find a solution.