# HiveQL - Create chains of group IDs

Tags: hiveql, hue

Let's say I have a table with 3 columns each containing a group ID like so:

[image]

I want the group ID column to be populated with an ID that links rows together based on the other 3 groups.

So looking at group 1 which I've populated manually,

rows 2 and 3 are contained in this group because they have the same A group

rows 2, 7 and 10 are contained in this group because they have the same C group

rows 6 and 7 are contained in this group because they have the same B group

All those rows are in the same group despite there being no direct link between some rows (e.g. row 2 and 6)

I typically have a simple solution for this in SQL where I simply do the following loop:

```
CLUSTER:
UPDATE A
SET A.GroupID = B.GroupID
FROM #TEMP A
JOIN #TEMP B ON B.GroupA = A.GroupA
             OR B.GroupB = A.GroupB
             OR B.GroupC = A.GroupC
WHERE A.GroupID>B.GroupID

IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0 GOTO CLUSTER
```

but obviously I can't do that on hive as you can't loop.

I searched online and found a similar question on stackoverflow but unfortunately the solution is a link to another question which has since been deleted (and also this person only uses 2 group columns whilst I have 3):
[SQL Server : chain grouping of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54077449/sql-server-chain-grouping-of-columns)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is a Graph problem, you can try the Spark GraphX

Comment: If your data amount is not large, you can try this using python or java collections.

Comment: unfortunately this has to be done in Hive, I can't use Python or Spark GraphX

Comment: you can try to write a Hive UDF  to solve this problem.